# How Cassandra choose clustering key when we only specify Primary key in a table

Tags: cassandra

We can specify `compound primary key` in `cassandra`. When we specify only one column as Primary key then how Cassandra will generate `clustering key`.
In cassandra primary key automatically becomes `partition key`.

Example :- 
CASE 1 - K1: primary key has only one partition key and no cluster key.

CASE 2 - (K1, K2): column K1 is a partition key and column K2 is a cluster key.

CASE 3 - (K1,K2,K3,...): column K1 is a partition key and columns K2, K3 and so on make cluster key.

In Case 1 how cassandra will choose the Clustering key for a given table with only Specifying Primary Key

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case no clustering key is provided (CASE 1), then cassandra will not choose any clustering key.

[How CQL3 maps to cassandra internal data structure](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/)

If you describe a table with such a primary key, you will not get `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY` option.